# How to place an image above another image using Styled Components in React Native App

Tags: ios, react-native, background, styled-components

I need to put an icon image above my cardVideo component. I just want to put the image above, without any action.

The path for the play icon: import image from '../../../assets/book_covers/icon-play.png';

Thank you.

My component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Capa, TextBox, Title } from './CardVideo.style';
import image from '../../../assets/book_covers/imageCollection';

const CardVideo = ({ item, first=false, last=false }) => (
  <SafeAreaView>
    <Container first={first} last={last}>
      <Capa source={image[item.imagem_livro]} resizeMode="cover" />
      <TextBox>
        <Title numberOfLines={1}>{item.titulo_livro}</Title>
      </TextBox>
    </Container>
  </SafeAreaView>
);

export default CardVideo;
```

VideoCard style:

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

export const Container = styled.View`
  margin-left: ${props => (props.first ? '16px' : '12px')};
  margin-right: ${props => (props.last ? '16px' : '0')};
  justify-content: space-between;
`;

export const Capa = styled.Image`
  width: 280px;
  height: 160px;
  margin: 0 0 12px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #000000;
`;

export const TextBox = styled.View`
  width: 280px;
  height: 42px;
`;

export const Title = styled.Text`
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #232728;
`;

export const IconPlay = styled.Image`
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  object-fit: contain;
`;
```

[The component image without the Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1pMw.png)

[How should it be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AVw3.png)

[How it looks like in the iOS simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QNC7.png)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with [Absolute Positioning in React Native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props#position) or even with [ImageBackground](https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground)

1. Ex: With Absolute Positioning: `position: absolute;`

```
// VideoCard style
export const ImageContainer = styled.View`
  width: 280px;
  height: 160px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;

export const Capa = styled.Image`
  width: 280px;
  height: 160px;
  border-radius: 10px;
`;

export const ImageOverlayView = styled.View`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  opacity: 0.3;
  border-radius: 10px;
`;

export const IconPlay = styled.Image`
  position: absolute;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
`;

//VideoCard Component Image part:
...
<ImageContainer>
  <Capa source={image[item.imagem_livro]} resizeMode="cover" />
  <ImageOverlayView />
  <IconPlay source={/* your image */)} />
</ImageContainer>
<TextBox>
...
```

2. Eg: ImageBackground - for placing Image above another image.

```
// VideoCard style 

export const ImageBackground = styled.ImageBackground`
  width: 280px;
  height: 160px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;

export const IconPlay = styled.Image`
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
`;



//VideoCard Component Image part:
...
<Container first={first} last={last}>
  <ImageBackground source={image[item.imagem_livro]} resizeMode="cover">
    <IconPlay source={/* your image */} />
  </ImageBackground>
  <TextBox>
...
```